# VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest lags when used with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: ios, swift, apple-vision

I am using a

> VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest

combined with a

> VNSequenceRequestHandler

to process images coming from the

> AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

delegate call:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

I want to be able to show the face landmarks in realtime, so that the user can see them overlaid over the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

So, as the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput delegate gets called, I then call:

```
func perform(_ requests: [VNRequest], on image: CIImage)
```

The CIImage comes from the CMSampleBuffer the delegate provides.

The problem is that the landmarks lag. As I move my face in front of the camera the landmarks are quite slow to update.

How can I update the landmarks so that they follow the face movement without lagging behind?

Comment: It takes some time to find the landmarks so that's why you have the lags. I know that you can use face tracking and I believe this is what you should use to track the face rather than search for the face with every single frame.